# How to lazy load a property with custom attribute

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I want to create a custom attribute using Glass Mapper for getting the Sitecore URL, because it is not possible to lazy load a property with `SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Url)` and we have some performance issues loading URL of mapped items, where the URL will never be used.

Here is what I've got so far:

### The Configuration

```
public class SitecoreUrlConfiguration : AbstractPropertyConfiguration
{
    public SitecoreInfoUrlOptions UrlOptions { get; set; }

    public bool IsLazy { get; set; }
}
```

### The Attribute

```
public class SitecoreUrlAttribute : AbstractPropertyAttribute
{
    public SitecoreUrlAttribute()
    {
        this.IsLazy = true;
        this.UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.Default;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether is lazy.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsLazy { get; set; }

    public SitecoreInfoUrlOptions UrlOptions { get; set; }

    public override AbstractPropertyConfiguration Configure(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var config = new SitecoreUrlConfiguration();
        this.Configure(propertyInfo, config);
        return config;
    }

    public void Configure(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, SitecoreUrlConfiguration config)
    {
        config.UrlOptions = this.UrlOptions;
        config.IsLazy = this.IsLazy;

        base.Configure(propertyInfo, config);
    }
}
```

### The Mapper

```
public class SitecoreUrlMapper : AbstractDataMapper
{
    public override object MapToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
    {
        var context = mappingContext as SitecoreDataMappingContext;
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new MapperException("Mapping Context is null");
        }

        var item = context.Item;
        var scConfig = this.Configuration as SitecoreUrlConfiguration;

        if (scConfig == null)
        {
            throw new MapperException("SitecoreUrlConfiguration is null");
        }

        var urlOptions = Utilities.CreateUrlOptions(scConfig.UrlOptions);

        urlOptions.Language = null;
        // now, what?
    }
}
```

So far, so good. But how can I lazy load the URL in the mapper? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: did you try Lazy<T>?

Comment: Yes, I tried Lazy<T>. But I'd like to have a String-Property in my model and not a Lazy<String>-Property. :-)

Comment: I don't think you can do that if the property type is going to be string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I actually see is to map a `Lazy<T>` and add a new property to the class which returns the value of this when accessing it. So in you mapper, where you put `// now what?` I would return the lazy string:

```
return new Lazy<string>(() => LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions));
```

Then in your model, put these two properties:

```
[SitecoreUrl]
public Lazy<string> LazyUrl { private get; set; }

[SitecoreIgnore]
public virtual string Url
{
    get
    {
        return this.LazyUrl.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve pretty similar to this with a bit of creativity and the new Delegate functionality

In the fluent configuration map the type like so:

```
SitecoreType<IWhatever> sitecoreType = new SitecoreType<IWhatever>();
sitecoreType.Delegate(y => y.Url).GetValue(GetLazyUrl);

private LazyString GetLazyUrl(SitecoreDataMappingContext arg)
{
    var item = context.Item;

    return new LazyString(
        () => 
        {
           // the necessary actions to get the url
        });
}

public class LazyString : Lazy<string>
{
    public LazyString(Func<string> valueFactory) : base(valueFactory)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(LazyString lazyString)
    {
        return lazyString.Value;
    }
}
```

It's not a string, but for the purposes of many applications, will behave like one.